# Need to query data in a specific format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to write a query which gives me data in a specific way, for example - Coulmns in database

```
ID Name   Equipment  Resolution       DateTIme  
1  xyz     Pace      Powercycle       2/10/2016 12:09
2  abc     Aris      Sent HIT         2/10/2016 12:09
3  xyz     PAce      Sent HIT         2/11/2016 12:09 
4  xyz     Pace      Trouble Call     2/13/2016 12:09
```

When the data returns after the query it should look like

```
Count(Equipment)  Resolution 1  Resolution2 
      1           Powercycle    **Sent Hit**     
      1           **Sent Hit**  Trouble call
```

**Sent Hit** from row 1 is same as that in row 2
How would i be able to achieve it?

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Please show your query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good place to start. The denizens here won't act as a code writing service, but will help you out if you've made (and show) an attempt. Good Luck!

Comment: Given the details in your question I suggest `print "Count(Equipment)  Resolution 1  Resolution2\n      1           Powercycle    **Sent Hit**\n      1           **Sent Hit**  Trouble call\n"`. If you need further help please stick with @Tim 's proposal.

Comment: Also, suggest you EDIT this question and provide the table structures AND the query you attempted.  There is no visible correlation from PowerCycle to Sent Hit, and then Sent Hit to Trouble Call.  There are obviously other details missing for any true answer / assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you look for the cartesian product

```
SELECT COUNT(a.Equipment), a.Resolution AS 'Resolution1', b.Resolution AS 'Resolution2'
FROM tablename a, tablename b
```

Comment: It is from the same table, i used case and rank function by date but all i get is :
Count(Equipment)  Resolution 1    Resolution2     Resolution3
      1                      Powercycle    **Sent Hit**         Trouble Call

Comment: 'it is from the same table'  - my query also only uses 1 table!
just replace 'tablename' with your tablename, leave the alias a and b